# mysql clean a log table when there are too much records

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a mysql database with a table storing logs. This table receives records every 10 second.

I would like to truncate my table every week, that means after 80.000 records. I'd like to do a stored procedure which checks at every insert if there are more than 80.00. If there are more, the table is truncated.
I can't find how to use the `if` statement with SQL.

I know it would be better to do a script in a crontab to connect to the db and delete the table once a week, but i have the constraint to do it directly by SQL stored procedure.

Thank you in advance for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with MySQL Event Scheduler, which is basically like cron, but runs as a thread within the MySQL Server. With it you can schedule the execution of an SQL statement or procedure.

First you have to turn it on:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Then you can create an event:

```
CREATE EVENT MyEvent
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK
  DO
    TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable;
```

Read more about it here:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for ! :)